# iOS Plugin Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, plugins

I am currently working on a augmented reality project. I would like to place some virtual objects on a human body. Therefore I created an iOS facetracking app(with openCV; C++) which I want to use as a plugin for Unity. Is there a way to build a framework from an existing iOS app? Or do I have to create a new Xcode project and create a cocoa touch framework and copy paste the code from the app into this framework? I am a little bit confused here. Will the framework have camera access?

My idea was to track the position of a face and to send the position to unity, so that I can place some objects on it. But I do not know how to do that. Can anybody help?

nice greets.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know you need to make your Unity project, and use assets like OpenCV, but it doesn´t allow you to track the human body (without markers).
About building a fremwork starting from an iOS app, first time I heard that!